# How can I pass particular <li> value with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a html file like-

**HTML- index.php**

```
<form name="myform" action="data.php">
  <ul>
    <li onclick=myform.submit();>
      <input type="hidden" name="soc" value="1">google</li>
    <li onclick=myform.submit();>
      <input type="hidden" name="soc" value="2">facebook</li>
    <li onclick=myform.submit();>
      <input type="hidden" name="soc" value="3">twitter</li>
    <li onclick=myform.submit();>
      <input type="hidden" name="soc" value="4">none</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
$val = &_POST["soc"];
echo $val;
?>
```

In this if I click anyone of this, it's passing only the last `<li>` value 4.
I want to get only this `<li>` value where I clicked.
I mean to say if i click on facebook, then I can get the value '2' in data.php file.

Comment: can you have event handler?

Comment: sorry  &_POST["soc"]; is  $_POST["soc"];

Comment: i really dont know about this. can i get some reference?

Comment: because input is hidden user not interacting and they are all classed as set, the last one "4" overwriting 1,2 and 3. use input type radio and hide with css, then get value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do that

create different form for each `li`.

```
<ul>
    <form name="myform1" action="data.php">  
        <li onclick=myform1.submit();><input type="hidden" name="soc" value="1">google</li>
    </form>
    <form name="myform2" action="data.php">  
        <li onclick=myform2.submit();><input type="hidden" name="soc" value="2">facebook</li>
    </form>

</ul>
```

2. Use jquery to replace the value by click event

Html

```
<form name="myform" action="data.php">
  <ul>
    <li id="1">google</li>
    <li id="2">facebook</li>
    <li id="3">twitter</li>
    <li id="4">none</li>
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="" id="myid" />
  </ul>
</form>
```

**Js**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(li).click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr(id);
        $("#myid").val(val);
        myform.submit();
        return true;
    })
})
</script>
```

3. pass values in `url` as query string.

Comment: Glad to know that.  Welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `form` just use `a` tag with url parameter, this may be the better and easiest way

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="data.php?soc=1">google</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="data.php?soc=2">google</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="data.php?soc=3">google</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="data.php?soc=4">google</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$val = $_GET["soc"];
echo $val;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use multiple hidden inputs with the same name and expect them behave as independent form elements. When submitting the form all the hidden inputs are sent as soc=1&soc=2&soc=3&soc=4
Leave a single hidden input with name="soc" and in each onclick attribute change the callback like:

```
document.forms.myform.soc=1;document.formsmyform.submit();
```

Change the number to the corresponding value for each li element

Answer (score 0):

In ajax you should use  `$val = $_POST["soc"]`. You can use ajax request as

**JS**

```
$(function() {

  $('.opt').on('click', function(){

    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "data.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {soc: val},
      success: function() {
        console.log('success');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li class="opt"><input type="hidden" name="soc" value="1">google</li>
<li class="opt"><input type="hidden" name="soc" value="2">facebook</li>
<li class="opt"><input type="hidden" name="soc" value="3">twitter</li>
<li class="opt"><input type="hidden" name="soc" value="4">none</li>
</ul>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$val = $_POST["soc"];
echo $val;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a purely jQuery/JS solution

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform" action="data.php">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="submitMyForm(1)">
      google
    </li>
    <li onclick="submitMyForm(2)">
      facebook
    </li>
    <li onclick="submitMyForm(3)">
      twitter
    </li>
    <li onclick="submitMyForm(4)">
        none
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function submitMyForm(val) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "data.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {soc: val},
      success: function() {
        console.log('success');
      }
   })
}
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/p0cf8c0L/